# How to create custom setting page for WordPress plugin?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

How I can print the value for Input form in PHP?

I'm trying to create a setting page for my WordPress plugin, and I have this code to add Input field in this setting page

```
function wprw_settings_init() {

    // Setup settings section
    add_settings_section(
        'wprw_settings_section',
        'wprw Settings Page',
        '',
        'wprw-settings-page'
    );

    // Registe input field
    register_setting(
        'wprw-settings-page',
        'wprw_settings_input_field',
        array(
            'type' => 'string',
            'sanitize_callback' => 'sanitize_text_field',
            'default' => ''
        )
    );

    // Add text fields
    add_settings_field(
        'wprw_settings_input_field',
        __( 'Input Field', 'wprw' ),
        'wprw_settings_input_field_callback',
        'wprw-settings-page',
        'wprw_settings_section'
    );
}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'wprw_settings_init' );


/**
 * txt tempalte
 */
//
function wprw_settings_input_field_callback(){
    
    // validate and update clink_countdown_duration value
    
    $wprw_input_field = get_option('wprw_settings_input_field');
    if( !is_numeric( $wprw_input_field ) ){
        update_option( 'wprw_settings_input_field', $value = 10 );  
        $wprw_input_field = get_option('wprw_settings_input_field');
    }
    
    ?>
        <input type="number" name="duration-time" id="wprw_settings_input_field" value="<?php echo $wprw_input_field; ?>" />

        <p class="description clink-description"><?php _e('Enter the redirect countdown duration in seconds (example : 20). In default it set to 10 (seconds).','wprw'); ?></p>
    <?php
}
```

When I add a number in this field I want to print this number in another page (Just the number). I tried this code `<?php echo wprw_settings_input_field_callback($wprw_input_field); ?>` but it's print all form design. How I can print the input value only?